# About the meaning of the title Priv-Doz

Tags: postdocs, professorship, germany

In Germany there exists the title *Priv-Doz* before the name of some professors. What does it mean? Do these professors allow to hire postdoctoral applicants?

Comment: A comment 'cause it's not what you are _really_ interested in. PD, a _Privatdozent_ title gives you a fancy diploma, an obligation to teach for, like two hours a week, and hopefully an incentive to be hired as a professor. All other standing is related to the _actual position_ that person holds, but not this title.

Comment: @OlegLobachev: Is the diploma really so fancy? If yes, why?

Comment: Udank: At least my diploma is. Not sure what's the reason, but the habilitation diploma is much less fancy that PD one, at least at my university.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Formally it is a title given to a university teacher, translation: private lecturer. It means you are able to teach, but not yet a professor.

In practice it is the required step-up from the PhD degree, to get a permanent position.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privatdozent

Comment: Can they hire postdocs?

Comment: Yes - I know of at least two examples. The would most likely need external funding to do something like that.

Comment: "In practice it is the required step-up from the PhD degree, to get a permanent position." At least for some fields, this information is outdated. There are alternative routes to permanent positions, including junior professorships (see the specified Wikipedia page).

Answer (score 5):

A *Privatdozent* (PD) is a university scholar who has a *Habilitation* and is thefore allowed to supervise PhD students, but is not (yet) a professor. They may hire postdocs if they can obtain funding. Unlike professors, their position usually doesn't come with funding for PhD students or postdocs. In fact, the title PD ist just that - a title. It doesn't indicate anything about the position that the PD may or may not have, except that they don't have the position of a professor.

In other words, in Germany and Austria a PhD thesis makes you a doctor, and a subsequent *Habilitation* makes you a PD. Traditionally, you need a *Habilitation* to be hired as professor.

Comment: Yep, that's the traditional way to a professorship. Still, there is "junior professorship" in some places (basically assistant professor in Anglo-Saxon world, with or without tenure-track), the "habilitation-equivalent accomplishments", leadership of elite research groups, such es Emmy-Noether programme, etc.